# Visual Studio C++ Debugger, get value from address

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, memory-address

if you just know the address of a variable and the type of it, is it possible to see it's value in the visual studio debugger? furthermore, would it be possible to use this address in a conditional or data breakpoint?

i already tried plain casting like this: (bool)(*0x05dc05d1) which is obviously stupid. ;)

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*(bool*)(0x05dc05d1)` should work.